# Como criar documento word com php?

Tags: php, relatório, microsoft-word

Boa tarde,

Como faço para gerar um relatório no formato office word(.doc ou .docx) com php?, assim como usamos as classes do php FPDF,TCPDF,MPDF para gerar relatórios em pdf, como podemos gerar relatório no formato aceito pelo Microsoft office word?, qual classe no php que me permite isso?.

Agradeço.

Comment: [PHPWord](https://phpword.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Também pode usar essa biblioteca: http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/

Comment: Aqui tem mais informação: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124959/create-word-document-using-php-in-linux

Comment: Votei como duplicata, pois mesmo a pergunta sendo um pouco diferente desta, a resposta la já responde a duvida, acredito eu. :) Edite a pergunta e evidencie se houver algo que difere.